# Permission to create Spatial Index

Tags: sql-server, index, spatial

Permissions required to create a Spatial Index on a table, for this [BOL says](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934196.aspx):

> Requires ALTER permission on the table or view. User must be a member
>   of the sysadmin fixed server role or the db_ddladmin and db_owner
>   fixed database roles.

However, I find that the ***Alter permission*** alone is sufficient to create a Spatial Index on a table. (without having server Sysadmin rights)

The test I have created below: (run each batch to find out what is happening)

```
USE adventureworks;
GO
/* Start these scripts with a priveledged account */

CREATE TABLE employees
(employeedid INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
empaddress GEOGRAPHY
)
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(47.656 -12.360, 47.656 -12.343)', 4326))
GO

/* Create our test SQL account with limited access = no securables yet */
CREATE LOGIN LimitedPerms WITH Password = 'pass';
CREATE USER LimitedPerms FOR LOGIN LimitedPerms;
GO

EXEC AS USER='LimitedPerms';
SELECT SUSER_NAME() AS 'CurrentlyLoggedInUser'
GO

/* Should give an error = does not have any rights yet */
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX emp_spatIx on employees(empaddress);
GO

REVERT;
SELECT SUSER_NAME() AS 'CurrentlyLoggedInUser';
GO

/* Give alter permission on table: employees to our test user */
GRANT ALTER ON OBJECT::employees to LimitedPerms;
GO

EXEC AS USER='LimitedPerms';
SELECT SUSER_NAME() AS 'CurrentlyLoggedInUser';
GO

/* Allows user to create index without being a sysadmin! */
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX emp_spatIx on employees(empaddress);
GO

REVERT;
GO
```

Anyone care to test and report back? or inform why documented like this?

Thanks

EDIT1: This was tested on SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition

EDIT2: I have put feedback on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/706766/books-online-suggested-permission-to-create-spatial-index-incorrect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft connect ticket was resolved with wording changed:

Please refer to link below (changes have not been made on BOL yet, 1 dec)

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/706766/books-online-suggested-permission-to-create-spatial-index-incorrect